# The ajax response is not got rendered in parent div of clicked hyperlink

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

In below code I have several hyperlinks. I want that whenever I click on any hyper link the a ajax request will be made and the response will be get
rendered in the parent div of the respective hyperlink by replacing the hyperlink. I have searched on google and tried several different code but the response is not get 
rendered in the parent div of the respective hyperlink. I checked the response and its coming properly.
You can find my few try commented in commented form.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stdlib/jquery-1-4-2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=idclick]').click(function(){
    alert("click");
    var tempid=this.id;
    //var divtemp=tempid.closest("div").attr("id").html(result);
    var divtemp=tempid.closest("div");
     $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            success: function(result) {
                //alert(this.href);
                //alert(divtemp);
                 //$("#iddiv").html(result);
                 //this.parentNode.html(result);
                 //var id = 
                 //var aid=this.id;
                //aid.closest("div").attr("id").html(result);
                divtemp.html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
testcss {
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="iddivone"><a id="idclick" href="TestCodeServlet?page=1">click here</a>Old data</div>
<div id="iddivtwo"><a id="idclickone" href="TestCodeServlet?page=1">click here</a>Old data</div>
<br>
<div id="iddivthree"><a id="idclicktwo" href="TestCodeServlet?page=1">click here</a>Old data</div>
<br>
<div id="iddivfour"><a id="idclickthree" href="TestCodeServlet?page=1">click here</a>Old data</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me in this problem. I know its very small problem but I still not get solved. I am sure I have made some silly mistake in it.

Please guide me in this friends!
Thank You!

Comment: What is the `dataType` for your ajax call?? Is it `html` or `json`??

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Thank You! Sir for your comment. "Why not giving all div elements other id ?" Its typing mistake and I have correct. "and then use $(id).html("") where id can be this.id" I this I cannot specify the id of the div because I want that the response should get rendered in the div whose hyperlink is clicked. So first of all I have to find out the div whose hyperlink is clicked.

Comment: why are you using same id for all divs? IDs (unlike class elements) should be unique. Why not giving all div elements other id and then use $(id).html("") where id can be $(this).parent().attr("id")?

Comment: i updated my comment. use $(this).parent().attr("id");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var divtemp = tempid.closest("div");
```

To:

```
var divtemp = $(this).closest("div");
```

`tempid` is just the id of the link, there is no `closest` method on that, you want to call `closest` on the element itself (`$(this)`)